# Getting Workset id's from the open project Revit API + python

Tags: python, api, revit

I am trying to get a list of workset name and id's from the active document using Revit API inside of Python node in Dynamo. I am trying to access workset table but this code returns nothing:

```
doc = __doc__

workset = ActiveWorkset(doc)
active_id = workset.ActiveWorksetId()

OUT = active_id
```

For now I was just trying to see if i can get active workset first but even that doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this in Dynamo, but my trusty RevitPythonShell thinks this should work:

```
worksetTable = doc.GetWorksetTable()
activeId = worksetTable.GetActiveWorksetId()
workset = worksetTable.GetWorkset(activeId)
```

this is based on the example from the Revit 2014 API document in the SDK...

The output:

```
>>> workset
<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Workset object at 0x000000000000002E [Autodesk.Revit.DB.Workset]>
```

Based on your example, you probably want to do this at the end:

```
OUT = activeId
```